# MeteorJS and Iron Router getting undefined on return data

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Anyone know what this works just fine

```
data: function() {
            return Topics.findOne(this.params._id); 
        }
```

But this does not

```
data: function() {
            return [Topics.findOne(this.params._id)]; 
        }
```

It's not finding the this.params._id

Comment: That is your actual code?

Comment: Just the data function part?

Comment: Yea, but it would be nice to see how you used this in the templates too, to make sure you're not doing anything wrong there.

Comment: Why would you want to return an array here?

Comment: @HubertOG need to return more then one value, bye the way are you looking for freelance work?

Comment: It would def help to see the rest of the route. Also your data object can return key value pairs (an associative array) so it probably does not make sense to return a flat array.

Comment: Thanks I ended up finding a workaround will update the question

Answer (score 0):

Did a simple workaround

```
return {
            _id: Topics.findOne(this.params._id)._id
        }
```

Comment: Didn't you "need to return more than one value"? :S And what's the point of finding a document by it's id and then just use it's id? Just return the id directly :)

Comment: Yes need to return more then one value, just posted the basic for the answer.